# How do I do cursor-up in Go?

Tags: go

How do I do “cursor-up” in Go? (Clear-to-end-of-line would also be good to know). (All platforms).

To elaborate and show the context, I’m writing a test program in Go that requires the input of some parameters (via console) that are stored in a text file and used as defaults for the next usage. I want to have some very rudimentary console “editing” features.

Currently it is fairly primitive because I don’t want to go deeply into console editing, I just want something fairly basic but also not too basic.

In the example below from my test program, the String variable “sPrompt” contains the prompt for the input, and to the right it shows the default and then there are backspace characters to position the cursor so that the default is not overwritten – like I said, very basic.

When the operator enters the input, if an error, I'd like to display an error message, and then in either case move the cursor up to the line just displayed/entered and if an error, then display the original line, or if correct, display just the prompt and the new parameter.

I did read somewhere that ReadLine() should be avoided, but it appears to do the job.

Example:

```
func fInputString(sPrompt string, asValid []string, sDefault string)
    (sInput string, tEnd bool) {

    oBufReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        print("\n" + sPrompt)
        vLine, _, _ := oBufReader.ReadLine()
        sInput = strings.ToLower(string(vLine))
        if sInput == "end" {
            return "", true
        }
        if sInput == "" {
            sInput = sDefault
        }
        // check for valid input //
        for _, sVal := range asValid {
            if sInput == sVal {
                return sInput, false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how sPrompt is constructed (not meant to be optimized):

```
if sDefault != "" {
    for len(sPrompt) < 67 {
        sPrompt += " "
    }
    sPrompt += sDefault
    for iBack := 20 + len(sDefault); iBack > 0; iBack-- {
        sPrompt += "\b"
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go

Answer (score -1):

With [tput](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) strings that control the cursor around the screen:

- `tput sc` to save the cursor position
- `tput rc` to restore the cursor position

Then using these strings in the Go function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const sc = "\u001B7"
const rc = "\u001B8"

func main() {
    fmt.Print(sc)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Print(rc + sc)
        fmt.Println(i, "one")
        fmt.Println(i, "two")
        fmt.Println(i, "three")
        fmt.Println(i, "four")
        fmt.Println(i, "five")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Should work in most terminals.

Comment: With macOS bash, each of the strings can be captured with `tput xx | pbcopy`, then pasted in Go source code.

Answer (score -2):

#### Make your own little shell

You should not reinvent the wheel and use a library which does exactly what you want.
A popular option is the [readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) which is [apparently](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm) available for Windows
as well. This is used, for example, by bash and ZSH. There are some Go wrappers for it:

1. https://github.com/shavac/readline
2. https://github.com/bobappleyard/readline

I personally would recommend [`bobappleyard/readline`](https://github.com/bobappleyard/readline) as it is better documented
and has a nicer API (less C-like). There does not seem to be a special build tag for
Windows, so you might have to write it for yourself but that should be not that hard.

[termbox](http://code.google.com/p/termbox/) and its (pure) Go implementation [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) which was already pointed out by @bgp does **not** seem to be good for simply reading a line as it seems to be more intended 
for full screen console applications. Also, you would have to code the up/down matching
and history yourself.

#### `.Readline()`

The doc is right by saying that you should not use this as it does not handle anything for
you. For example, reading from a stream that emits partial data, you have no guarantee that you will get a full line from `Readline`. Use [`ReadSlice('\n')`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadSlice) for that.